# C# Bunifu - How can I use/call any type of Bunifu control on a custom class?

Tags: c#, windows, bunifu

I created a custom class. I want to create a Bunifu button on that class, the problem is the only type of controls that Visual Studio let me create is the defaults one, because I used the (System.Windows.Forms) library.
How can I call a bunifu button on a class? Maybe call some library? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

All you'll need to do is add a reference to the *Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.dll* control in your project by navigating to where the file is located in your Computer, then you can write this sample code in your main Form's `Load` event:

[C#]

```
            Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton bunifuButton = 
            new BunifuButton.BunifuButton();

            bunifuButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 70);
            bunifuButton.ButtonText = "Hello world";

            bunifuButton.Click += (senderObject, eventArgs) => {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello there..."); 
            };

            Controls.Add(bunifuButton);
```

[VB.NET]

```
            Dim bunifuButton As New Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuButton.BunifuButton()

            bunifuButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 70)
            bunifuButton.ButtonText = "Hello world"

            AddHandler bunifuButton.Click, Sub(senderObject, eventArgs)
                MsgBox("Hello there...")
            End Sub

            Controls.Add(bunifuButton)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference to Bunifu framework you can download it from their website

https://bunifuframework.com/products/bunifu-ui-winforms/

add `Bunifu_UI_v1.5x.dll` to your ptoject
Go to `toolbox--> Choose Items --> Browse`
 Select the dll file and you will have all the tools including Bunifu Button.

Comment: you gonna have to pay for it, if you loose your licence you wont even be able open your project, I wouldn't recommend to use bunifu framework for your projects

Comment: I have the dll bro, I don't think you understood my question. I have a class and I want to declare a button from code. Like Button button_example = new Button(), I wanna do that with bunifu right? But it wont let me, maybe because of a library or something.